# how can i print the values from the dcn file after specific pattern found in linux

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have input like this,

```
[Data.11]
Store,100,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,5222
Store,101,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,5235
[Data.12]
TaxSchedulePt,5899,2,110.0100,99999999.99,,8.8750
TaxSchedulePt,5900,1,0,110.00,,0.0000
[Data.13]
TaxSchedulePt,5900,1,0,110.00,,0.0000
TaxSchedulePt,5900,2,110.0100,99999999.99,,8.8750
```

---

first need to find the [Data.*] has found in the given input file, If [Data.*] found in the given input file need to write that specific [Data.*] values into separate file.

---

Expected output file for[Data.11]

```
Store,100,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,5222
Store,101,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,5235
```

---

Expected output file for[Data.12]

```
TaxSchedulePt,5899,2,110.0100,99999999.99,,8.8750
TaxSchedulePt,5900,1,0,110.00,,0.0000
```

---

Expected outputfile for [Data.13]

```
TaxSchedulePt,5900,1,0,110.00,,0.0000
TaxSchedulePt,5900,2,110.0100,99999999.99,,8.8750
```

---

And this is i have tried,

```
filename=$1
Var1=Data.18
if grep -wq "$Var1" $filename ;
then
 awk '$1 ~ /Data[.]18/' > /ttk/new/data.dcn
else
echo "not Worked"
fi
```

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. Please edit your question and include the expected output, aswell as what you have already tried.

Comment: I tried to fix the formatting. It is not clear if `[Data.18]` etc should be part of the input file. Please check this and fix it if necessary.

Comment: What if both are found? Should only [data.18] values be printed, or only [data.16], or both?

Comment: Need to write the separate outfiles. If [Data.16] found write a separate file and if [Data.18] was found write a separate file.

Comment: @EdMorton , Its working as expected after changed the file format CRLF into LF....Thank you so much..Once again Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

`awk 'BEGIN{d=0;p=0} d==1&&/\[Data\.[0-9]+\]/{p=0} p==1{print} /\[Data\.[0-9]+\]/&&d==0{p=1;d=1}'`

Explanation: at start of day, we are not printing a section (p=0) and we have not found a data section (d=0). If p==1, we are printing, print the line. If a data line is encountered and we have not found a data section yet, turn printing on and record that we have found a data section. If a data section is found but we have already found a data section, turn printing off.

Comment: If i give like  this awk 'BEGIN{d=0;p=0} d==1&&/\[Data\.[0-9]+\]/{p=0} p==1{print} /\[Data\.[0-9]+\]/&&d==0{p=1;d=1}' it will try Data.[0-9] but i want to print exactly [Data.18] valus only as per my output

Comment: i want to create a separate files for every [Data.*] if not expected [Data.*] was present in the input should not create the files. Please find my below input file format                                  "[Data.1]
AllTaxAuthorities
[Data.2]
TaxAuthority,1,Sales Tax,,,,,,,,,,,,,
[Data.3]
AllTaxZones
[Data.4]
TaxZone,5222,CTRY,"MA                            ","MA                                                "
TaxZone,5234,CTRY,"NO NEXUS                      ","NO NEXUS                                          
[Data.16]
AllTaxRuleAssigns
[Data.18]
Store,100,,,,,,5222 and so on.....

Answer (score 0):

If `i want to print exactly [Data.18] valus only` as you said in [one comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/656410/how-can-i-print-the-values-from-the-dcn-file-after-specific-pattern-found-in-lin#comment1235037_656418) is your correct requirement (and changing `18` to `12` given your updated sample input) then:

```
$ awk '{sub(/\r$/,"")} /^\[/{key=$1; next} key=="[Data.12]"' file
TaxSchedulePt,5899,2,110.0100,99999999.99,,8.8750
TaxSchedulePt,5900,1,0,110.00,,0.0000
```

or if `If [Data.16] found write a separate file and if [Data.18] was found write a separate file` as you said in [another comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/656410/how-can-i-print-the-values-from-the-dcn-file-after-specific-pattern-found-in-lin#comment1235040_656410) is your correct requirement then:

```
$ awk '{sub(/\r$/,"")} /^\[/{close(out); out=$1; next} {print > out}' file

$ head *Data*
==> [Data.11] <==
Store,100,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,5222
Store,101,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,5235

==> [Data.12] <==
TaxSchedulePt,5899,2,110.0100,99999999.99,,8.8750
TaxSchedulePt,5900,1,0,110.00,,0.0000

==> [Data.13] <==
TaxSchedulePt,5900,1,0,110.00,,0.0000
TaxSchedulePt,5900,2,110.0100,99999999.99,,8.8750
```

The above were run against this input file:

```
$ cat file
[Data.11]
Store,100,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,5222
Store,101,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,5235
[Data.12]
TaxSchedulePt,5899,2,110.0100,99999999.99,,8.8750
TaxSchedulePt,5900,1,0,110.00,,0.0000
[Data.13]
TaxSchedulePt,5900,1,0,110.00,,0.0000
TaxSchedulePt,5900,2,110.0100,99999999.99,,8.8750
```

The `sub(/\r$/,"")`s are to remove the CRs at the end of lines with DOS line endings (which the OP has) and, despite it causing field splitting to occur and so having a small performance hit, we're using `$1` instead of `$0` in case the input lines have trailing blanks that would then be undesirable in the key value or output file names.